# Defining/Setting the color of JComboBox BasicArrowButton in case of disabling

Tags: java, user-interface, overriding, jbutton, jcombobox

I didn't like the standard arrow button of the JComboBox, because it didn't fit well in my GUI. So I changed it. To do this, I wrote a class, which is extending `BasicComboUI`. In the regular case, everything is like I am expecting it. But as soon as I am disabling the button, it stays the way it is, which means that the button doesn't get the grey background color anymore. Instead, the left part of the list does. So I would like to know, if there is a way to define or to modify the disabling-behavior of the arrow button.

Here is my current code:

```
public class CustomArrowUI extends BasicComboBoxUI{

private static Color buttonBackground;
private static Color borderBox;
private static Color arrowColor;
private static Color buttonBorder;



public static ComboBoxUI createUI(JComponent c, Color buttonBackground, Color borderBox, Color arrowColor, Color buttonBorder)
{
    CustomArrowUI.buttonBackground = buttonBackground;
    CustomArrowUI.borderBox = borderBox;
    CustomArrowUI.arrowColor = arrowColor;
    CustomArrowUI.buttonBorder = buttonBorder;

    return new CustomArrowUI();
}


@Override
protected JButton createArrowButton()
{
    JButton button = new BasicArrowButton(BasicArrowButton.SOUTH, buttonBackground, borderBox, arrowColor, buttonBorder);
    LineBorder border = new LineBorder(buttonBorder, 1);
    button.setEnabled(false);
    button.setBorder(border);
    return button;

}}
```

What I could do is setting the background light grey as default, and change the color in the ActionListener of the previous button, which is enabling my JComboBox. But I kinda don't like this solution. I would prefer to do it directly in my `CustomArrowUI`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one short way to solve this. I added a `ChangeListener` to my arrow button, which is checking if the button is enabled or not, and coloring the button:

```
@Override
protected JButton createArrowButton()
{
    final JButton button = new BasicArrowButton(BasicArrowButton.SOUTH, buttonBackground, borderBox, arrowColor, buttonBorder);
    LineBorder border = new LineBorder(buttonBorder, 1);
    button.setEnabled(false);
    button.setBorder(border);
    button.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
            if(button.isEnabled())
                button.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            else
            {
                button.setBackground(ColorPalette.LIGHT_GREY);
                button.setBorder(new LineBorder(ColorPalette.LIGHT_GREY, 1));
            }
        }
    });
    return button;  
}
```

Above I changed the background of the button and the border color too make it look like the arrow is part of the JComboBox, and not like a separate button inside of it.

Since the disabling-behavior is inheritet from the JComboBox itself (I guess), I don't need to take care if the button is usable or not. All I need to define is the color.
Another important point is to make sure, to call the `setEnabled()`-method after setting the UI of the JComboBox, if the JComboBox should be disabled by default. Otherwise it will not react initially, and the arrow button will look enabled.